# Android Webview Crash While Selecting Text

Tags: android, android-webview

i am trying to select text in android web view with the follow method

```
KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0,0,
                         KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,0,0);
                    shiftPressEvent.dispatch(webView);
```

but while selecting app get crash

log displayed while crash is

```
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318): Build fingerprint: 'archos/g8/G8A/:2.2.1/FROYO/eng.rd.20110419.192729:user/test-keys'
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318): pid: 2766, tid: 2766  >>> org.medulla <<<
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  r0 005b7a00  r1 beff628c  r2 14000101  r3 005b7a00
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  r4 005b7a00  r5 beff628c  r6 00000000  r7 beff628c
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  r8 beff6418  r9 4186ba88  10 4186ba70  fp 00000000
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  ip 00000000  sp beff6228  lr ab163ad4  pc ab180c44  cpsr 20000010
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d0  643a64696f72646e  d1  7fffffff7fffffff
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d2  0000020a7fffffff  d3  000002197fffffff
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d4  4402000041f00000  d5  00000000422c0000
02-01 19:17:27.407: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d6  3f0b67ec3f0ba2e9  d7  0000000000000000
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d8  4069400000000000  d9  40695000000000ca
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d10 5575757575551718  d11 5555555555555555
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d12 adadadadadadbec6  d13 adadadadadadadad
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d14 abacacacacaac0c3  d15 abababababababab
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d16 4069400000000000  d17 7e37e43c8800759c
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d20 3ff0000000000000  d21 8000000000000000
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0016000400080014
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d24 0005003f003f0000  d25 002d000900110029
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d26 10a2ffffffff0000  d27 b5b621244228a534
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 3ff0000000000000
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
02-01 19:17:27.415: INFO/DEBUG(1318):  scr 6000001a
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318):          #00  pc 00080c44  /system/lib/libskia.so
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318):          #01  lr ab163ad4  /system/lib/libskia.so
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): code around pc:
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): ab180c24 e590202c e24dd01c e1a04000 e1a05001 
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): ab180c34 e3a0b000 e5806028 e1520006 9a000030 
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): ab180c44 e4963004 e2433001 e5846028 e353001d 
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): ab180c54 908ff103 eafffff7 ea000288 ea000276 
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): ab180c64 ea000265 ea000256 ea00023b ea00021d 
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): code around lr:
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): ab163ab4 e3a01003 e1a04000 e1a0e00f e593f014 
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): ab163ac4 e1a01004 e1a05000 e1a00006 eb007225 
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): ab163ad4 e1a00004 e1a01005 e8bd4070 eaffff28 
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): ab163ae4 e92d41f0 e24dd030 e28d5008 e1a04000 
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): ab163af4 e1a07001 e1a06002 e1a00005 e59d1048 
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318): stack:
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff61e8  00000001  
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff61ec  afd0c6e7  /system/lib/libc.so
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff61f0  00000000  
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff61f4  00000400  
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff61f8  00000258  
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff61fc  00000000  
02-01 19:17:27.603: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6200  00000000  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6204  00000054  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6208  beff6238  [stack]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff620c  00000068  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6210  00000002  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6214  00000068  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6218  00000003  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff621c  afd0cd51  /system/lib/libc.so
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6220  df002777  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6224  e3a070ad  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318): #00 beff6228  005f5e14  [heap]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff622c  ab12e74c  /system/lib/libskia.so
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6230  005f5e14  [heap]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6234  beff62c0  [stack]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6238  beff628c  [stack]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff623c  ab12e798  /system/lib/libskia.so
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6240  005f5dd4  [heap]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6244  00000000  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6248  40694000  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff624c  beff628c  [stack]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6250  00000001  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6254  00504bf8  [heap]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6258  beff628c  [stack]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff625c  beff6418  [stack]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6260  4186ba88  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6264  4186ba70  
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff6268  beff6758  [stack]
02-01 19:17:27.610: INFO/DEBUG(1318):     beff626c  ab163ad4  /system/lib/libskia.so
02-01 19:17:28.001: DEBUG/Zygote(1227): Process 2766 terminated by signal (11)
02-01 19:17:28.048: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1319): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5414 objects / 546376 bytes in 78ms
```

The dispatch method is deprecated so is there any other chance to select text or its possible to avoid crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23901